# Unity хранение строк в одном файле

Tags: c#, строки, unity3d, локализация, unity3d-editor

Делаю средний проект. Замаячила на горизонте необходимость перевести его на другой язык. Программируя на Android. Знаю что очень удобно хранить все строковые переменные в одном файле. В Android это xml. Как это правильно организовать в Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я могу сказать, как мы с своих играх делаем.

1. В отдельной системе (с веб мордой) вбиваем локальки на разные языки и т.п.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Для каждого языка в этой системе генерится json. Обычный плоский список, который десериализуется в `Dictionary<string, string>` на клиенте.
3. В Unity3d в редакторе перед билдом скрипт стучится к нашему серваку с этими json'ами и качает их в папку `Resources`. В итоге, все локальки попадают в билд.
   После закачки в папку с ресурсами импортируем

   ```
   UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path, UnityEditor.ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate);
   ```
4. У нас для игр нужен интернет, поэтому у ещё при запуске игры происходит сверка версий локалек локальных с версиями на серваке. Если они обновились, то качаем новые.
5. В самом unity локальки десериализуются в `Dictionary<string, string>`, где просто брать локальки по ключу. Читаем из ресурсов и десериализуем:

   ```
   var txt = Resources.Load(path) as TextAsset;
   var words = DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(asset)
   ```
6. Грузится локалька в зависимости от языка системы [`SystemLanguage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemLanguage.html) (по-умолчанию EN).

Comment: Непосредственно в самой игровой логике где храните и как вызываете?

Comment: @RodGers обновил ответ.

Comment: То есть в каждом месте, где нужны строки обращаетесь к файлу, или всё же менеджер?

Comment: @RodGers менеджер. Из файла мы читаем один раз при запуске и пишем в `Dictionary` все строки. Потом уже с ним работаем.